# Bash Alias for Pressing Up in the Command Line

Tags: bash, command-line, alias

I personally hate having to go down to press the up-arrow-key when I want to repeat a command on the command line.

Is there a way to have map a bash alias to pressing the up-arrow-key? Or something that's also as convenient? I would like to just press 'n' then 'enter' instead of 'up-arrow-key' and then 'enter'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, bash uses the emacs keybindings.  Ctrl-p and ctrl-n (for previous and next) do the same as up and down arrow.

To view and edit interactively, bash gives you the builtin `bind` command.  `help bind` shows you usage, and, for example, `bind -P` shows you all the current bindings.  Any remapping you do can be put into your .inputrc file for next time.

Also, bash provides what it calls HISTORY EXPANSION, similar to what was present in older shells.  Just type `!!` and hit enter to execute the previous command.  There's an entire section in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) with extra features.

Finally, I'll note that if you are repeating commands so often that hitting `up-arrow enter` is annoying, you might consider writing a script to do whatever you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can issue the command `set -o vi`, or add it to your startup file.  Then, you can hit the escape key and use the movement keys from vi to scroll.  You can use `k` to scroll backwards, `j` to scroll forward, and `h` and `l' to move left and right.